# Is there a way to not write 'sudo' for using git in macOS?

Tags: git, sudo, macos-catalina

I'm on macOS Catalina, every time I use git commands I have to use `sudo git $CMD`; without it the errors like `unable to access '/Users/$USER/.config/git/...': Permission Denied` persists.
I would like to fix this **globally** such that I don't have to write sudo for every repository.

Comment: This situation arises from using sudo at least once in the past when you should not have. The fix you posted is OK since nothing in `.config` should be owned by anyone else, but you shouldn't need to do this in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Global fix:

`sudo chown -R ${USER}:${GROUP} "/Users/${USER}/.config"`

If there's no group,

`sudo chown -R ${USER} "/Users/${USER}/.config"`

Credit goes to TheDevMinerTV on Discord(CS Army) for the solution.